# Facebook cannot retrieve the contents of my site

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

When I paste a url of my site (http://www.podhlato.gr) on facebook it doesn't retrieve its title, description or any image.

I have tried adding the open graph meta tags but it didn't help at all.
I have tried using the facebook linter tool to find out what's wrong and I get a 200 response code but still it has no access to the contents of any url from my site.
In the Object Properties section I get:

```
     og:url: http://podhlato.gr/
    og:type: website
   og:title: http://podhlato.gr/
```

og:updated_time: 1324124626

In the scraped url it shows only a doctype (!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd") and it's not even the doctype I use on my pages. Something is preventing facebook from accessing any page from my site.

I 've hit a dead end here and I have no idea what's going wrong. Do you suspect anything? Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You have no `og:tags` in the source code of your homepage (http://www.podhlato.gr).  You **must** have `og:tags` if you want facebook to see the correct information about your URL.
You can use [this reference of the Open Graph Protocol](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/) to know what tags you should place on your page.

Comment: I have added the og: tags... again!
It still doesn't work. 

In the source code I can read them clearly but facebook cannot retrieve them.

Comment: `<meta property="og:title" content="Online αγορές ποδηλάτων κάθε τύπου. Παιδικά, Γυναικεία, Mountain, Trekking, City, Κούρσες, ΒΜΧ, Σπαστά, Ηλεκτρικά, Αξεσουαρ. |podhlato.gr"/>
 <meta property="og:type" content="website"/>
 <meta property="og:url" content="http://podhlato.gr/index.php?route=common/home"/>
 <meta property="og:image" content="http://podhlato.gr/catalog/view/theme/bike-theme/image/sport-fitness-logo.png"/>
 <meta property="og:site_name" content="Podhlato.gr"/>
 <meta property="og:description" content="All about bikes"/>`

Answer (score 0):

i cant find related og codes in your website's source 
the source code i see is exactly what facebook shows it :

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/echo?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.podhlato.gr%2F